# apache is not converting relative url to absolue url when its rendered on clientbrowser

Tags: html, apache, relative-path, relative-url

my problem is "apache is not converting relative url to absolue url when its rendered on clientbrowser"

i posted here the code that's on localhost and the html code rendered on clients machine.
the problem is apache is not doing ANYTHING to th relative url. just let it stay as the same as its on server's html code

this is the code on localhost (which is site.dev) ;

```
 <html>
 <head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>

 <!--this is not converting to absolute on client side -->
 <!-- thus my js app is not working-->
 <script src="app.js"></script>  

 </head>
 <body></body>
 <html>
```

here is the interpereted,rendered html on client machine;

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>

      <!--here relative url stays the same .why APACHE why? -->
       <script src="app.js"></script>
     </head>
<body>
</html>
```

shouldt  this

```
 <script src="app.js"></script>
```

already have been converted into this By APACHE2

```
 <script src="https://site.dev/app.js"></script>
```

please help me.

Comment: Apache won't magically change your web page, it just serves the files on the server. If the link is "app.js" in the file, that's what the browser will get.

Comment: yes its in the same folder as html